# IntelliJ connection reset trying to git pull when connected to VPN

Tags: git, intellij-idea, http-proxy

Everything works fine when I'm not connected to VPN. But when I connect to VPN and configure a proxy script on my system (Windows 10), IntelliJ is not able to do any remote git operations.

I have tried configuring the proxy script in IntelliJ Proxy settings, the "Check connection" part gives "Connection Successful" to the same git remote. Tried Invalidate/Restart as well.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2021.1.3

Thanks

Comment: IDE relies on command-line Git, if git is not working in cmd.exe then it won't work properly in IntelliJ. Could you please check git operations when you are using VPN? 
Otherwise you may require to configure `git config --global http.proxy`

Comment: Yes, my command line git was not working either. Looks like I need to configure a local proxy server that uses the proxy script, as git doesn't support configuring proxy through a pac file. Thanks @Ruslan Kuleshov

Comment: This means you have a networking troubleshooting issue, and so is not appropriate for this site. Please delete it and re-ask it on https://superuser.com

Comment: The issue was resolved by configuring the proxy itself. No troubleshooting required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the proxy with command-line git fixed the issue.

"Check connection" just tries to connect to the given URL using the IntelliJ Proxy settings. However, all the git operations depend on the command-line git (whichever is configured in the settings).

So I had to go through the proxy script (.pac file) and find the IP address and port from there and configure it using `git config --global http.proxy` command.

Thanks @Ruslan Kuleshov for the tip